# How best to deploy android apps and allow updates

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

We have an android app all ready to go to our customer however it cant be installed on the google play store cause it is a corporate app,so what are my options to enable remote updates to the apk file obv I can enable developer mode on the devices but as its only two handsets do we need to go to the expense of a provisioning tool what do other people do in relation to this.

We are developing in xamrian forms but I guess this is a general Android question as well.

Comment: Hockey app is best for internal distributions of application, you can also maintain the version in hockey app, this is free app with some number of application limitation in free version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [Hockey app by Microsoft](https://hockeyapp.net/#) for internal distribution.

Comment: is it free as part of office 365 or is their also a user based subscription

Comment: its a great solution thank you I see it free tier allows unlimited distributions ;-)